COLOR EN DESPLEGABLE CONDICIONAL
Quiero lograr hacer desplegables condicionales.
Las listas deplegables son proyectos y actividades(estas dependen del proyecto)
El código me funciona, pero a lista de deplegables del proyecto yo le cambio manualemnte los colores, ya que cada proyecto tiene su color, pero una vez que finalizo de cambiar, se desaparece el color que le asigne y queda el proyecto pero sin color,no se que puedo agregarle al código para que me permita hacer el cambio de colores manual de las deplegables del proyecto.
Dejo mi código si alguien me ayuda por favor :
function onEdit(e) {
  crearDesplegablesCondicionales();
}

function crearDesplegablesCondicionales() {
    // Nombres de las hojas
    const hojaProyectos = "Base de Datos"; // Hoja que contiene los proyectos y actividades
    const hojaFormularioNombre = "ATEV_JAINZ"; // Hoja donde estarán los desplegables

    // Columnas y filas relevantes
    const columnaProyectoBD = 1; // Columna A en "Base de Datos" (Proyectos)
    const columnaActividadBD = 2; // Columna B en "Base de Datos" (Actividades)
    const inicioProyectosBD = 4; // Fila inicial en "Base de Datos"
    const inicioDesplegables = 3; // Fila inicial para desplegables en "ATEV_JAINZ"
    const columnaProyectoFormulario = 1; // Columna A en "ATEV_JAINZ" (Proyectos)
    const columnaActividadFormulario = 2; // Columna B en "ATEV_JAINZ" (Actividades)

    // Obtener hojas
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const hojaDatos = ss.getSheetByName(hojaProyectos);
    const hojaFormulario = ss.getSheetByName(hojaFormularioNombre);

    // Leer datos de "Base de Datos"
    const lastRowBD = hojaDatos.getLastRow();
    const datosBD = hojaDatos.getRange(inicioProyectosBD, 1, lastRowBD - inicioProyectosBD + 1, 2).getValues();

    // Crear lista de proyectos únicos y un mapa de proyectos -> actividades
    const proyectosUnicos = [...new Set(datosBD.map(row => row[0]))].filter(Boolean); // Proyectos únicos sin valores vacíos
    const actividadesPorProyecto = {};
    datosBD.forEach(row => {
        const [proyecto, actividad] = row;
        if (!actividadesPorProyecto[proyecto]) {
            actividadesPorProyecto[proyecto] = [];
        }
        if (actividad) actividadesPorProyecto[proyecto].push(actividad);
    });

    // Determinar el rango dinámico para los desplegables en "ATEV_JAINZ"
    const lastRowFormulario = hojaFormulario.getLastRow();
    const rangoProyectos = hojaFormulario.getRange(inicioDesplegables, columnaProyectoFormulario, lastRowFormulario - inicioDesplegables + 1, 1);

    // Crear validación para proyectos sin afectar el color manualmente establecido
    const valoresProyectos = rangoProyectos.getValues();
    const coloresProyectos = rangoProyectos.getBackgrounds();
    const reglaProyectos = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
        .requireValueInList(proyectosUnicos, true)
        .build();
    rangoProyectos.setDataValidation(reglaProyectos);
    rangoProyectos.setValues(valoresProyectos); // Restaurar valores originales
    rangoProyectos.setBackgrounds(coloresProyectos); // Restaurar colores originales

    // Crear validación condicional para actividades en cada fila con datos
    for (let fila = inicioDesplegables; fila <= lastRowFormulario; fila++) {
        const celdaProyecto = hojaFormulario.getRange(fila, columnaProyectoFormulario);
        const celdaActividad = hojaFormulario.getRange(fila, columnaActividadFormulario);
        const proyectoSeleccionado = celdaProyecto.getValue();

        const valorActividad = celdaActividad.getValue();
        const colorActividad = celdaActividad.getBackground();

        if (proyectoSeleccionado && actividadesPorProyecto[proyectoSeleccionado]) {
            const actividades = actividadesPorProyecto[proyectoSeleccionado];
            const reglaActividades = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                .requireValueInList(actividades, true)
                .build();
            celdaActividad.setDataValidation(reglaActividades);
        } else {
            celdaActividad.clearDataValidations();
        }

        // Restaurar el valor y color original de la celda de actividad
        celdaActividad.setValue(valorActividad);
        celdaActividad.setBackground(colorActividad);
    }
}


Esto es un script para google docs ???
